# how to make all special symbols available in org latex?

Tags: org-mode, latex

once use the command below:

```
C-x RET C-\ TeX RET
```

I try to make some math formula:

```
\sqrt{}
```

but it can't be automatic translated to √,
then I check the symbol list:`C-h I`
and also can't find the \sqrt tex item,
so is there a config I have missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you're not missing anything. For whatever reason, the TeX input method doesn't include include the macro `\sqrt`. You can get that symbol under its secret name, `\surd`.

This is arguably a bug which could be fixed by inserting a rule for `\sqrt` in the `latin-ltx--define-rules` form in the file `leim/quail/latin-ltx.el`. I don't follow that macro, but it would probably also be possible to add the rule in your config if you knew the name of the appropriate variable (which I don't as of yet).

## Update

Bug report submitted to https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=25594  ...